# How to iterate through vector size and assign to new vector?

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a vector container, and I generate a random string (as of right now it's
just asterisks for the sake of me being able to easily see the differences in size) to assign through the vector. All is fine and dandy, got everything working with that..

When I pass the vector to a function that is supposed to iterate through and assign the size
of each element in the vector to a new vector, I always get an error. What is the best way to do this?

The code below is not my original attempt, but I'm late for class and have to run. So as of right now, here's how I'm trying to do it.

```
vector<int> siz;
int length = contain.size();
for (vector<string>::iterator i = contain.begin(); i != contain.end(); ++i){
    siz.push_back(contain.size());
}
for (vector<int>::iterator j = siz.begin(); j != siz.end(); ++j){
    cout << *j << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Look carefully at the line `siz.push_back(contain.size());` and what exactly it is doing.

Comment: I don't get the point. You want `contain.size()` copies of `contain.size()`?

Comment: For this particular build, I don't receive an error. It just pushes back the sum number of elements in the contain vector, which I understand why it's doing. My problem is that I'm trying to get the string size of each element in the contain vector, not the sum size of the vector.

Comment: basically I guess I can rephrase my question as why does siz.push_back(contain[*i].size()); not work even after i change the vector to type int? I mean it's obvious that the types are different but what is my workaround here?

Comment: `i` is an *iterator*, not an index. You can use it as though it were a pointer to the current element of the container (as you correctly do in the second loop).

Comment: `for (auto const& s : contain) siz.push_back(s.size());`, and that size vector should contain `std::string::size_type`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the size of each individual element, rather than the length of the container vector.

Your `i` variable is an iterator on the container vector, which operates essentially as a pointer to each element.  In the body of your loop, access the size of the object `i` points to, to get the size of that object.

```
vector<int> siz;

for (vector<string>::iterator i = contain.begin(); i != contain.end(); ++i){
    siz.push_back(i->size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention, you want a vector `siz` that contains the length of each `string` in the vector `contain`, correct? If so, you do not want to do `contain.size()` because that is just the length of your string vector. To get the size of *each string*, see below.

```
vector<int> siz;

for (vector<string>::iterator i = contain.begin(); i != contain.end(); ++i){
    string currentString = *i;
    siz.push_back(currentString.size());
}
```

Comment: Or skip the copy and just use `siz.push_back(i->size());`

Comment: @FredLarson You are correct, though I deliberately split it up into two steps so OP could see what exactly `i` was and what was different from their code.